# Python: Using lambda inside lambda returns lambda object

Tags: python

I was reading a snippet that uses lambda inside a lambda then i wanted to test it out by creating a dummy function that reads from a file then returns the maximum and minimum number.

This is what I came up with

```py
dummy = lambda path: (lambda x, y: (lambda data: ([y for x in open(path, "r").readline().splitlines() for y in x])[0])(min(data), max(data)))
```

With a little bit of formatting, this is how it looks(IMHO one liner is much more readable.)

```py
dummy = lambda path: (
    lambda x, y: (
        lambda data: ([y for x in open(path, "r").readline().splitlines() for y in x])[
            0
        ]
    )(min(data), max(data))
)
```

But it always returns the lambda object

`Out: <function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fe26f00a4c0>`

or this

`'function' object is not subscriptable; perhaps you missed a comma?`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well you need to call `soru1` otherwise it's a `lambda` object

Comment: @PranavHosangadi it's dummy actually, i unforgot the change it.

Comment: Split the statement over multiple lines. One lambda per line. Then build up your big lambda. You're forgetting to call one of the nested lambdas.

Comment: What is this function's interface supposed to be? How did you want it to be used? I can see problems with the code, but not how it was *supposed* to work.

Comment: For example, `dummy` tries to use `data`, but there is no `data` in `dummy` - the only `data` variable is the parameter to the inner `lambda`, so no value of `data` exists when `dummy` tries to use it.

Comment: On the other hand, the inner `lambda` takes a `data` parameter, but makes no use of it whatsoever.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks for the explanation, I wanted to run it like `dummy("path.txt")` then I want to create an array with that file in my case `lambda data:` , then I wanted to use my x,y lambdas and I expect from them to run `min(data)` and `max(data)`

Comment: If it is possible can you provide an example?

Comment: Is there a reason you want this as lambdas?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes, i found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/e000/1023982) today, which became super interesting to me so I'm just playing with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dummy = lambda path: (
    lambda x, y: (
        lambda data: ([y for x in open(path, "r").readline().splitlines() for y in x])[
            0
        ]
    )(min(data), max(data))
)
```

Let's split this over a bunch of lines.

```
lamb1 = lambda data: ([y for x in open(path, "r").readline().splitlines() for y in x])[0]
```

This doesn't look right -- why never use data?

Next:

```
lamb2 = lambda x, y: lamb1(min(data), max(data))
```

`lamb2` calls `lamb1` with 2 arguments -- min and max of `data`. Where'd `data` come from? And why are we passing *two* arguments to a lambda that only wants one?

And finally:

```
dummy = lambda path: lamb2
```

So dummy is a lambda that when called, returns the lambda `lamb2`. You never call `lamb2`, so you can't expect it to return a value. If you *did* call `lamb2`, you'd get an error.

It's hard to think through and debug one-liners, so let's define this as a regular function first.

```
def dummy(path):
    lines = [int(x) for x in open(path, "r").readlines()]
    smallest = min(lines)
    largest = max(lines)
    return (smallest, largest)
```

Now to convert each line to a lambda:

```
readfile = lambda file: [int(x) for x in open(file, "r").readlines()]
minmax = lambda data: (min(data), max(data)
dummy = lambda path: minmax(readfile(path))
```

And joining these lambdas:

```
dummy = lambda path: (lambda data: (min(data), max(data)))((lambda file: [int(x) for x in open(file, "r").readlines()])(path))
```

If I set `data.txt` to

```
100
23
2349
20
21
1
```

and then ran this as

```
dummy("data.txt")
```

I get the output:

```
(1, 2349)
```

---

Note that we still have a bug - we're not doing proper cleanup. We open a file, but we never close it. That's *usually* not a problem due to the reference counting mechanics of the CPython implementation, but reference counting is an implementation detail, and other implementations don't do it.

To fix this problem, the best way is to use a `with` statement:

```
def dummy(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        lines = [int(x) for x in f.readlines()]
    smallest = min(lines)
    largest = max(lines)
    return (smallest, largest)
```

but there is, deliberately, no "`with` expression". Python isn't designed to encourage stuffing everything into a big one-liner expression.

If we want to write our big one-liner `lambda` and still do proper cleanup, the solution closest to the spirit of the problem is to define a helper:

```
def with_(resource, code):
    with resource as x:
        return code(x)
```

Then we can translate

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    lines = [int(x) for x in f.readlines()]
```

to

```
lines = with_(open(path, 'r'), lambda f: [int(x) for x in f.readlines()])
```

and incorporating that into our big one-liner,

```
dummy = lambda path: (lambda data: (min(data), max(data)))((lambda file: with_(open(path, 'r'), lambda f: [int(x) for x in f.readlines()]))(path))
```

While we're at it, we might as well iterate over `f` directly instead of building a list with `readlines` and then iterating over that:

```
dummy = lambda path: (lambda data: (min(data), max(data)))((lambda file: with_(open(path, 'r'), lambda f: [int(x) for x in f]))(path))
```

Answer (score 2):

This version of your code runs each of the lambdas and prints the first line of the file given to it as a parameter.

The main thing I had to do is wrap your lambda declarations in another set of parentheses.  It seems that what you thought was a set of parentheses that would cause the lambda to be called turns out to be taken as part of the body of the lambda.  Adding a set of parens around the lambda solves this.

Then I had the problem where your parameter names didn't really make sense, so just to get it to do something, I put in literal values instead.

Finally, your innermost lambda needed to be called before its return value, a list containing the lines of the file, could be acted on with `[0]`.

This prints the first line of the text file I'm giving it the path to:

```
dummy = lambda path: (
    (lambda x, y: (
        (lambda data: ([y for x in open(path, "r").readline().splitlines() for y in x]))(3)[0]
    ))(1, 2)
)

print(dummy("/tmp/data.txt"))
```

Result:

```
Test file - Line #1
```